# mpd can only use alsa sound device if run as root - how can I run it als non-root

Tags: linux, audio, permissions, mpd

I try to run mpd on fedora 23 using alsa (pulseaudio removed). However, when running mpd as user "mpd", I get

```
alsa_output: Error opening default ALSA device: Permission denied
```

So I ran it as user root, and everything is fine. Ok, permission problem - its just that I don't understand why its not working as user mpd - permissions look fine to me:

```
/dev/snd:
total 0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  0 Jan  1  1970 controlC0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 16 Jan  8 20:38 pcmC0D0p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 17 Jan  1  1970 pcmC0D1p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  1 Jan  1  1970 seq
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 33 Jan  1  1970 timer
[root@sh02 ~]# grep audio /etc/group
audio:x:63:isaac,mpd
[root@sh02 ~]# getenforce 
Permissive
```

And of course I have rebootet just to make sure everything gets properly initialized.
Anyone got an idea what is missing to let mpd acces my audio device? I could probably add some acl to allow mpd explicit access - but in my understanding the group membership should be sufficient ???

**EDIT** 
This are the permissions of the mpd config file:

```
-rw-r-----. 1 root root system_u:object_r:mpd_etc_t:s0 13585 Jan  8 22:04 /etc/mpd.conf
```

Notice that mpd can run as user mpd if using the pulse output plugin. But because pulse did stutter and also sometimes not start, I decided not to use pulse but use the alsa output.

There are no .mpdconf files in any homes.

Comment: Do you have a file in your home called `~/.mpdconf`? If so, what permissions does it have? What permissions has the file `/etc/mpd.conf`?

Comment: I have updated my question with the requested info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding acls to explicitly allow mpd access to the sound devices solved the problem:

```
sudo setfacl -m u:mpd:rw /dev/snd/*
```

Bevor doing this, the acls were like this:

```
# file: dev/snd/controlC0
# owner: root
# group: audio
user::rw-
user:lightdm:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::---

# file: dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
# owner: root
# group: audio
user::rw-
user:lightdm:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::---

# file: dev/snd/pcmC0D1p
# owner: root
# group: audio
user::rw-
user:lightdm:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::---

# file: dev/snd/seq
# owner: root
# group: audio
user::rw-
user:lightdm:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::---

# file: dev/snd/timer
# owner: root
# group: audio
user::rw-
user:lightdm:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::---
```

Since mpd was already member of the audio group, these acls should have been sufficient. I will give the bounty to the one able to explain what was going on here.

Answer (score -1):

You must add the user to the audio group:

usermod -aG audio [user]

Logout and and back in. You should be able to use audio.

Comment: Please read the question properly. The user was already member of the audio group. It did not work, even though it should have, according to group permissions. Which is why I posted this question in the first place :)